# Hide menu on scroll down then show the menu when the scroll up reach 0 [javascript] not working for me

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I've got a problem when I'm trying to create a menu effects.  I've got this JavaScript code from the other and paste into my code but sad to say doesn't work for me and I don't know what is the reason.

Here is my code:

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>NMSC</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/global.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nav-slide.js">
</head>

 <body>
 <nav class="nav-main">
 <div class="logo">Website</div>
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Library System</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Rules & Regulation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Service Hours</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">The Library</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div class="big-wrapper">
<header>
    <h1>NMSC Online Library</h1>
</header>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.nav-main {
z-index: 99;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
background-color: #222;
height: 50px;
color: #fff;

box-shadow: 5px 4px 5px #333333; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 4px 5px #333333; 
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 4px 5px #333333;
}
```

JavaScript for the menu:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var d = $('.big-wrapper'); 
    if (d.offset().top < 400) {
       $('.nav-main').fadeIn();       
    } else {
       $('.nav-main').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Now I've got what the problem it is; when I do this on JavaScript file:

```
alert('hello');
```

JavaScript popup when I reload the page then when I do this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
 alert('hello');
});
```

then scroll, nothing happens.
I also tried to paste your answer on plain scratch but its seems the same: nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, connect jquery library:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Now, you should get `body` scroll postion, and verify if it is lower than needed value (400 in your case). This should be done when `document` is ["ready"](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h06zpy12/1/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    $(window).scroll(function () {     
        if ($('body').scrollTop() < 400) {
           $('.nav-main').fadeIn();

        } else {
           $('.nav-main').fadeOut();
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: doesn't work for me... pasting the html, css, js from your demo to scratch file..  well.. nothing happen...  whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the position of a static element (d, which is .big-wrapper). If you want to hide your floating menu, then you should do like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var d = $('.nav-main'); 
if (d.offset().top < 400) {
   $('.nav-main').fadeIn();

} else {
   $('.nav-main').fadeOut();
      }
});
```

Comment: and now I've got what the problem it is.. when i do this on javascript file..
  
    alert('hello');
  
javascript popup when i reload the page then when I do this..
  
    $(window).scroll(function () {
     alert('hello');
    });

then scroll.. nothing happen.....
i also tried to paste your answer on plain scratch but its seems the same.. nothing happen.